# User input and do while loop with negation

Tags: java

I was trying to make an user input in an do while loop. The loop should continue if the user input is not yes OR not.
    When I write:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput = "";
    String yes = "yes";
    String no = "no";

    do {
        System.out.print("Type yes or no: ");
        userInput = input.readLine();
    } while (userInput.equals(yes) || userInput.equals(no));
```

If the user type "yes" OR "no" the loop will continue, all other inputs will result the end of the loop.

When I write:

```
while (!userInput.equals(yes) || !userInput.equals(no));
```

The loop continues everytime, no matter what the user enters.

Only when I use the AND operator it works.

```
while (!userInput.equals(yes) && !userInput.equals(no));
```

Why is that so?
Should it not be the OR operator because I want to say, if the user enters yes OR no stop the loop.

Comment: *"I want to say, if the user enters yes OR no stop the loop"* Then why don't you program it that they? You programmed it to say "When the user enters 'yes' ___or___ 'no', then keep looping". Your issue here the basic concept of a `do/while` loop and basic boolean algebra. Do some research on that and you can answer that question yourself.

Comment: You should ensure that user did not type 'yes/no' that's why your last condition works, others - not.

Comment: Thank you very much all. That answers my question. You are all great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!userInput.equals(yes) || !userInput.equals(no)
```

Let's say the user enters "hello". You ths have

```
!false || !false
```

which is

```
true || true
```

which is

```
true
```

Let's say the user enters "yes".

You thus have

```
!true || !false
```

which is

```
false || true
```

which is

```
true
```

Let's say the user enters "no".

You thus have

```
!false || !true
```

which is

```
true || false
```

which is

```
true
```

So you see that, whetever the user enters, the condition is always true, and thus the loop continues forever.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the Boolean expressions you are writing. When the users enters 'yes', it evaluates as `!true || !false` which is equivalent to `false||true` which is `true`. Since the condition is satisfied, the loop continues.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is how boolean expressions work. The opposite of A || B is not !A || !B but !(A || B) which is the same as !A && !B.

Answer (score 0):

`if( A || B)` means either A true or B true. If say A is true then it won't check B it will directly go inside the block. So when you say `if(!yes || !no)` and if you enter yes then second condition becomes true and when you enter no the first condition becomes true and it continues to execute. And if you enter `abdc` its again true.